# No Route Matches [GET] with # or ? parameter error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this route:

```
# :chwid => Camera Hardware ID - :mid => Machine ID - :fs => FormatString
get '/videocams/video/:chwid/:mid/:fs' => "videocams#get_videocams_id", :constraints => { :chwid => /[^\/]+/, :mid => /[^\/]+/, :fs => /[^\/]+/ }
```

But when I call the route, my first parameter ***:chwid*** contains the character ***#*** and ***?***:

> (@device:pnp:\?\root#image#0000#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global)

and an error is called:

> Started GET "/videocams/video/@device:pnp:%5C%5C?%5Croot"
>
> ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "videocams/video/@device:pnp:%5C%5C":

What might be triggering this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

URL-escape characters that have meaning in URLs lie `#` and `?`.

Comment: But my constraints don't ignore these meanings except the character "/"?

Comment: @gumaro Did you try URL-escaping them? I don't recall for sure, but I thought the `#` and `?` chars were handled separately from the segment constraints.

Comment: Where should I do it? in route?